# How to convert Viber's voice message files to common audio file?

Tags: audio, files, viber-messenger

Viber's voice message files are located in `/sdcard/viber/media/.ptt/` directory, and they don't have any extension format on them. I'm looking for a solution to convert them to a `common audio file` format.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site anymore for more than 5 years, and existing answers have no votes). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have voice tags on your phone or tablet. They are in the folder `sdcard/Viber/media/PTT`. They are designated by numbers 1, 2, ... without the extension.

1. First you need to install Viber on your computer.
2. Install Audacity on the PC as well.
3. Run Viber on the PC and let somebody send a short voice message to you. If this is the first voice message after installation, it will be labeled "1" and will be in the `\users\%username%\documents\viberdownloads\ppt`.
4. Delete this message and replace it with a sound file from your tablet or computer. (I send the file by email from tablet to PC). Be careful that the file had to be the same name as deleted file and had no extension.
5. Start Viber and test play a sound file.
6. Run Audacity. Select the correct input source (at the microphone icon) - in my case SoundMaxDigitalAudio-stereo mixer. Enable recording.
7. In Viber, play voice recording and let the whole recording play.
8. In Audacity, stop recording and save the recording as a "file in another format", e.g. mp3.

Further reading: [How to Save Voice Messages that you Received on Viber](https://web.archive.org/web/20201216220558/https://tjosm.com/3908/how-save-voice-messages-received-viber/) (archived)

Answer (score 0):

In `Memory/Android/data/com.viber.voip/files/.ptt`, you'll find all the *.m4a audio files.